# How to delete the ith item from a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column (char varying) that has ten items.
I need to delete the first item like "k45"
How should I do?

Values in my colum:

```
k45
e58
f65
s58
```

Comment: Create a new database model, this problem is exactly why normalization makes sense.

Comment: The question is not clear.  Do you want to delete the record or nullify the column?

Comment: I want to delete the record of the first item , then save them like e58 f65 s58

Comment: What about a delete query: DELETE FROM tablename WHERE value = 'k45';

Comment: The problem with this question is that "first" is not defined. Why would `k45` be "the first"? There is no natural order in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the first item" in a table.  Tables represent unordered sets.  You need a column for the ordering.

If you have such a column:

```
delete from t
    where id = (select min(id) from t where value = 'k45');
```

If you don't have such an `id` you can delete one row using `ctid`, a built-in identifier:

```
delete from t
    where ctid = (select min(ctid) from t where value = 'k45');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have distinct value in the column, then below should work

```
delete from tablename where column_name in
(select column_name from
(select column_name from tablename
order by rowid asc)
where rownum<2);
```

Comment: That's not valid for Postgres